# Two Representation Matrices of a Vector Space Must be Equivalent

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, representation-theory

I had previously posted a similar question, but I've reduced it to a much simpler case, so I deleted the other post and am creating this one to focus on the crux of the question.

In a class I'm taking, we've defined $A \in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ to be a representation matrix of a vector space $V$ (over $\mathbb{F}$) if there exists an isomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{F}^n / \mathbb{F}^n A \rightarrow V$. This is equivalent to the existence of a surjective map $f: \mathbb{F}^n \rightarrow V$ with kernel $A$, which I think is a more standard definition.

Here I'm considering the case where $V = \mathbb{F}^n / \mathbb{F}^n A$ for some $A \in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ so trivially $A$ is a representation matrix of $V$ using the identity map as the isomorphism. Let's suppose that $V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}^n/ \mathbb{F}^n B$ for some $B \in M_n(\mathbb{F})$, such that $B$ is another representation matrix of $V$. How can we show that $A = PBQ$ for some invertible matrices $P$ and $Q$?